Which communication type should I use in zeromq to redirect the message from my proxy to a specific server
I am developing a project in which the following needs to happen:

The clients send their objects through a proxy. The proxy then needs to decide which server is responsible for handling that specific object (through its id) ; I am using consistent hashing in the servers
The server then needs to send the handled object back to all clients that have that object ID.

The way I though about handling this was:

In one way of the communication (clients -> proxy -> servers) it would have client (REQ) -> (Router) Proxy (Dealer) -> (Rep) Server. However this came with a problem that, from what i understood in a Dealer I am not supposed to direct my message to a specific destination as it uses round-robin. Using REQ-ROUTER for client-proxy makes sense to me as perhaps, the proxy is connected to a lot of clients it should be able to handle asynchronous communication. But in the other end what should I use since i can't use Dealer-Rep ? Req-Rep ? Router-Req?

In the other way of communication i was thinking about a pub sub.


I am relatively new to distributed systems so any help would be very much appreciated :)
